# query string at page 1 in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin, pagination

```
        $pagination = createPagination(array(
            "url" => base_url("admin/product/index/page"),
            "total" => 10,
            "segment" => $this->segment,
            "perpage" => $this->perPage,
            'suffix' => '?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
        ),TRUE);
```

and pagination

```
function createPagination($setting = array(),$query_string = ""){
    $CI = get_instance();
    $CI->load->library('pagination');

    $config['base_url'] = $setting["url"];
    $config['total_rows'] = $setting['total'];
    $config['per_page'] = $setting['perpage'];  
    $config["uri_segment"] = $setting['segment'];   

    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination pagination-sm m-t-none m-b-none">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';

    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    if($query_string ){
        //$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
        $config["suffix"] = $setting["suffix"];
        $config["query_string_segment"] = "page";
    }
    //$config['anchor_class'] = "active";

    $CI->pagination->initialize($config);
    return $CI->pagination->create_links();
}
```

pagination working very well with query string but problem is that when i start pagination and back to page 1 it remove query string itself from page 1. like.. 
at page 2 :

```
http://127.0.0.1/stone/admin/product/index/page/1?search_in=1&search_type=&search_product_name=&search_product_category=46599528&search_product_status=1&search=search
```

and when i return from this page to page 1 it remove all query string data. 
like

```
http://127.0.0.1/stone/admin/product/index/page/
```

i want all data again on every pages.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `base_url` as following

```
...
base_url("admin/product/index/page/".$page_no."?search_in=".$search_in."&search_type=".$search_type."&search_product_name=".$search_product_name."&search_product_category=".$search_product_category."&search_product_status=".$search_product_status."&search=search")
....
```

Got the idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use

'reuse_query_string' => TRUE

In place of

'suffix' => '?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']